# App Display and mobile display not matching react native

Tags: android, react-native

How can I make my app full screen? It can be change from setting display size. Other app looks nice but my app looks horrible.

Please help suggest.

[image: parent not matching with app]

Comment: haha. what the hack is that ?
check other apps are they also coming with same way ?

Comment: it is 'samsung s8' and this type of device showing same